# Using TailwindCSS to fix a bg image relative to its div?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, css-grid

I'm using TailwindCSS and looking to place a decorative background image at the bottom-center of a grid item. However, using the `bg-fixed` class makes the image relative to the *entire DOM*.

Is there any way to fix a background image so that it's fixed to its div?

See below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `fixed` position, you can use an `absolute` position.
Here's an example using the `absolute` positioning on the `bg image fixed to panel's bottom`:

```
<div class="flex h-screen">
  <div class="w-1/2 overflow-auto border-8 bg-green-400">
    <header class="text-center">Scrollable Content</header>
    <p class="h-[5rem] border-2">Text</p>
    <p class="h-[5rem] border-2">Text</p>
    <p class="h-[5rem] border-2">Text</p>
    <p class="h-[5rem] border-2">Text</p>
    <p class="h-[5rem] border-2">Text</p>
    <p class="h-[5rem] border-2">Text</p>
    <p class="h-[5rem] border-2">Text</p>
    <p class="h-[5rem] border-2">Text</p>
    <p class="h-[5rem] border-2">Text</p>
    <p class="h-[5rem] border-2">Text</p>
    <p class="h-[5rem] border-2">Text</p>
    <p class="h-[5rem] border-2">Text</p>
    <p class="h-[5rem] border-2">Text</p>
    <p class="h-[5rem] border-2">Text</p>
    <p class="h-[5rem] border-2">Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="relative w-1/2 bg-pink-400">
    <header class="text-center">Decorative Panel</header>
    <div class="absolute bottom-0 right-[30%] h-[10rem] w-[10rem] border-2 bg-[url('https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/383/891/589/colorful-abstract-simple-wallpaper-preview.jpg')] bg-cover">Fixed Panel</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="h-screen border-8 bg-slate-400">Next Page...</div>
```

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/6o2yquLaZF)

---

##### Explanation about the structure:

I split the composition into 2 `div`s. Each `div` takes `100vh` (`h-screen`). We're going to focus on the first `div`.

This `div` is composed of 2 other `div`s, each taking half the screen's width (`w-1/2`). The first part contains scrollable content (green), and the second contains the decorative panel (pink). In the decorative panel, I placed a small panel with a background image. This bottom panel is relative to the decorative panel.
The decorative panel got the `relative` class, and the bottom panel got the `absolute` class.

In order to center the bottom panel to the middle of his parent element, I used the `bottom-0 right-[30%]` utilities.

---

[image: full image]

Comment: The problem with this solution is the background image is meant to be fixed while scrolling. But this would work for anyone that wants it to be absolute.

Comment: I was still able to use this by implementing the nested div tags with the child tag being fixed instead of absolute (and width being set to 1/2)